# ClojueScript Transit-cljs - map

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to use transit-cljs in order to consume some JSON service and turn it into a cljs data-structure.

In my cljs code I do:

```
(def r (transit/reader :json))
(def json (generate-string {:foo "bar" :baz 5}))
(def data (transit/read r json))
```

I am no be able to access this like a map now? something like:

```
("foo" data)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying this in ClojureScript :

```
  (def r (transit/reader :json))
  (def json "{\"foo\":\"bar\", \"baz\" : 123}")
  (def data (transit/read r json))
  (println "JSON " json)
  (println "DATA " data)
```

Yields the following in my browser :

```
JSON  {"foo":"bar", "baz" : 123}
DATA  {foo bar, baz 123}
```

I am not sure where your function `generate-string` comes from though.

You should have noted the following error :

```
("foo" data) ;; Uncaught TypeError: "foo".call is not a function
```

You can do either :

```
(data "foo")
(get data "foo")
```

I personally like the second more when there is a string and no keyword.